# PLese what is wrong with mySql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, string, xampp, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id int(11)  auto_increment primary key,
    f_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    l_name VARCHAR(255) not NULL,
    u_name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone int(15) not null UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR not null UNIQUE,
    pwd VARCHAR not null,
    confpwd VARCHAR not null,
    state VARCHAR(255),
    lga VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null,
    preference enum('m','f','mf') DEFAULT 'mf',
    gender enum('m','f') DEFAULT null,
    profile_image VARCHAR(255),
    bio VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT null,
    forgot_pwd_code VARCHAR (255),
    forgot_pwd_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    hobbies_id int(11),
     FOREIGN KEY (hobbies_id) REFERENCES hobbies (userId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i keep getting this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL UNIQUE, phone int(15) not null UNIQUE, email VARCHAR not null' at line 5

Comment: You need to specify a value for VARCHAR every time, not just some of the time. You shouldn't specify a value for int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VARCHAR` datatypes requires a length (that represents the maximum number of characters allowed) - not providing it is a syntax error.

This is true not only for column `uname`, but for also for `pwd` and `confpwd`. Each of these columns should be declared like `varchar(<N>)`, where `<N>` is the length of the column, instead of just `varchar`.